# With Quarkus and Panache, specify the entities to use from an external library

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

The project includes multiple micro services.

All of my Panache entities are declared in their own project, and this project is included as a maven dependency in the other projects that need them. The reason they are centralised in an external library is because multiple project will use the same DB (most of them in read only).

My problem is that the lib contains all of the entities of all the projects. So any project that includes this library will create a DB containing all of the tables of all the declared entities.

How can I configure quarkus to choose which entity or which folder of entities to use instead of using every entity detected in the external lib ?

**Edit - What I have tried** :

- setting `quarkus.hibernate-orm.packages=my.specific.entities.package` in `application.properties`. **Result: no effect**

Comment: Are you sure `quarkus.hibernate-orm.packages` doesn't work? Because that's what I was going to recommend and I was expecting it to work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure yes, I manually trashed the DB and restarted my app with `quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create`, and it recreated all the tables, including the ones from entities not in the declared package

Comment: for further inquiries https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Quarkus. should be solved in v2.6 : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21682

Comment: I have backported this for 2.5.1.Final that I will release on December 1st so you should be good to go in 2 days :).

Comment: that is awesome, thank you !